# Click through images and text with a tkinter GUI in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a pandas database with slides and text named "df_slides". I would like to make a tkinter GUI to click through the slides and display the text, like that:

[image]

This is what I have implemented so far:

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import base64
import pandas as pd

i = 0
def load_next_img():
    global pil_image, tk_image, i, text

    i = i+1
    base64string = df_slides["Slide_Image"][i]
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(base64string)
    pil_image =  Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
    tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
    label['image'] = tk_image

    text = df_slides["Text"][i]



def load_previous_img():
    global pil_image, tk_image, i, text

    i = i-1
    base64string = df_slides["Slide_Image"][i]
    imgdata = base64.b64decode(base64string)
    pil_image =  Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
    tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
    label['image'] = tk_image

    text = df_slides["Text"][i]





root = tkinter.Tk()
label = tkinter.Label(root)
label.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
load_next_img()

nextbutton = tkinter.Button(text="next", command=load_next_img)
nextbutton.pack()
backbutton = tkinter.Button(text="back", command=load_previous_img)
backbutton.pack()

T = tkinter.Text(root, height=10, width=30)
T.pack()
T.insert(tkinter.END, text)


root.mainloop()
```

This is the current result:

[image]

As you can see the text does not use the full width and more importantly it does not update together with the slide when I press "next" and "back". The slide updates but the text stays the same all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T.insert(tkinter.END, text)` must appear in the functions `load_next_img` and `load_previous_img`. For me the easiest way is to define a class 'Slides' to get the namespace right. Note to update the label use `self.label.configure(image=tk_image)`

Below an example where I have commented out the dataframe but should give a hint on how to resolve. Note to clear the text I have also added a line `self.T.delete('1.0', tkinter.END)`

```
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import base64
import pandas as pd


class Slides:

    def __init__(self):
        self.text_array = ['hello there', 'good bye']
        self.pic_array = ['test_1.jpg', 'test_2.jpg']

        self.root = tkinter.Tk()

        nextbutton = tkinter.Button(text="next", command=self.load_next_img)
        nextbutton.pack()
        backbutton = tkinter.Button(text="back", command=self.load_previous_img)
        backbutton.pack()

        self.slide_image = tkinter.Label(self.root)
        self.slide_image.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")

        self.text_box = tkinter.Text(self.root, height=10, width=30)
        self.text_box.pack()

        self.i = -1
        self.load_next_img()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def load_next_img(self):
        self.i += 1
        # base64string = df_slides["Slide_Image"][i]
        # imgdata = base64.b64decode(base64string)
        pil_image =  Image.open(self.pic_array[self.i % 2])
        pil_image = pil_image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)  # just for my convenience
        tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=pil_image)
        self.slide_image.configure(image=tk_image)
        self.slide_image.image = tk_image

        text = self.text_array[self.i % 2]
        self.text_box.delete('1.0', tkinter.END)
        self.text_box.insert(tkinter.END, text)

    def load_previous_img(self):
        self.i -= 1
        # base64string = df_slides["Slide_Image"][i]
        # imgdata = base64.b64decode(base64string)
        pil_image = Image.open(self.pic_array[self.i % 2])
        pil_image = pil_image.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS) # just for my convenience
        tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=pil_image)
        self.slide_image.configure(image=tk_image)
        self.slide_image.image = tk_image

        text = self.text_array[self.i % 2]
        self.text_box.delete('1.0', tkinter.END)
        self.text_box.insert(tkinter.END, text)


def main():
    slides = Slides()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

To get the positioning right for the buttons, label and text I would advice to use `grid`, rather than `pack`.

*PS. I took the liberty to change the variables `label` to `slide_image` and `T` to `text_box`*

Comment: Thank you very much !! May I ask why you write "self.i %2" and not just "self.i" ? Thanks.

Comment: This is modulus over 2 so it just loops over my 2 values in the array, you can implement your solution with the Pandas dataframe as you feel fit. If this has answered your question appreciate if you can confirm as solved. Thanks.

Comment: Alright. Yes, it did. Thanks a lot for your kind help !